# Convert UTC time to yyyymmdd format Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to convert a date object to UTC and then convert it to yyyymmdd format. 
Here is my code

```js
var scheduleDate = '2016/10/29 17:00';
var d = new Date(scheduleDate);
var utcdate = d.toUTCString();

var mm = utcdate.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var dd = utcdate.getUTCDate();

alert( [date.getUTCFullYear(), !mm[1] && '0', mm, !dd[1] && '0', dd].join(''));
```

But I'm getting the below error:

`utcdate.getUTCMonth is not a function`

How can i get the month and date from a UTC string date format ?

Comment: Remove the `var utcdate = ...` line and call the UTC-methods on `d` directly

Comment: getUTCMonth() is a method on the Date prototype, your code's attempting to use it on a string object (utcdate). You can use it (and the other Date proptotype functions) on your d variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `utcdate` is a string and so it does not have `getUTCMonth` or `getUTCDate` methods.

Further down you call the `getUTCFullYear` method on a variable that is not defined: `date`.

Finally, the way you try to pad with zeroes will not work, as `mm` and `dd` are not strings, and so when you index them with `[1]`, JavaScript will coerce these numbers to `Number` objects, but they don't have a `1` property, even when they have two digits. So you'll always get the padded `0` on top of that.

If you would fix that by first coercing those numbers to strings, it still would not work, as the `&&` operator will yield `false` in some cases, which will be output as such: `false`.

Long story short, there are easier ways to get the UTC yyyymmdd format of a date. For example by extracting it from the left side of the `yyyy-mm-ddThh:nn:ss.....` format that [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) returns:

```js
var d = new Date('2016/10/29 17:00');

console.log(d.toISOString().replace(/-|T.*/g,''));
```

Be aware that the UTC date is at some moments in time one day off compared to the date in the local time zone. If you need to prevent that, then I would suggest using [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) with a locale that has a [big-endian date format standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Gregorian.2C_year-month-day_.28YMD.29), such as Sweden, Lithuania, Hungary, South Korea, ...:

```
date.toLocaleDateString('se')
```

To remove the delimiters (`-`) is just a matter of replacing the non-digits:

```js
var d = new Date('2016/10/29 17:00');

console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('se').replace(/\D/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the known date is for UTC time zone, you can create the date object using the `Date.UTC()` method, then you can display the date local to the client (browser) time zone like so:

```js
//var scheduleDate = '2016/10/29 17:00';
// If known date is in UTC, create the date object like so:
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(2016,(10 - 1),29,17,0));

// UTC version of the date
var mmUTC = d.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var ddUTC = d.getUTCDate();
var hhUTC = d.getUTCHours();
// local to the browser (client) time zone
var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
var dd = d.getDate();
var hh = d.getHours();

// display values
console.log('UTC values: hour:['+ hhUTC +'] month:['+ mmUTC +'] day:['+ ddUTC +']');
console.log('Client Time: hour:['+ hh +'] month:['+ mm +'] day:['+ dd +']');
console.log('Client yyyymmdd:['+ d.getFullYear() + ((mm < 10) ? '0'+ mm : mm) + dd +']');
```